# Calculating resistance in theory

Tags: resistance, parallel, series

I'm studying about calculating the Equivelant Resistance in some circuits and I haven't figure out how to calculate this one
[image]

I thought the way to go was to do `4k + 6k + (Req(R2, R3, R4) in parallel with 20k)`, I guess I was wrong since the answer is 22k Ohm for the total resistance measured between A and B
Can someone try to explain me what's the process thought behind a circuit like this?

I got this circuit derivative from here:
[image]

**EDIT:**
Sorry for bothering I tried to cut corners and when calculating the Equivalent resistance I did 1/63k + 1/18k = 81k/1134k and was supposed to be 81k/1134M
Did the same on the other resistance in parallel, sorry to bother you with this silly mistake

Comment: R3 and R4 values are Ohm or kOhm?

Comment: Ohm, those were resistance that were on parallel and that is the value for the equivalent resistance

Comment: What answer did you get then? I guarantee it is not 20k by the way.

Comment: If we have 14kohm and 10kohm for R3 and R4 we end up with 22 kohm between A and B. But 20 kohm is hard to get, unless serious typing mistakes in the values. The expression written by @AndréClérigo is correct by the way.

Comment: Something way far from 22k, sorry i edited the post the answer is 22k and not 20k. I will post the full circuit because thats the answer

Comment: It is kOhm then

Comment: So, yes, we have 14 and 10 kohm, and the rsulting value is 22 kohm. Electrotechnics survived, I can go to bed :)

Comment: 18k and 63k in parallel is not 14 ohms. 10 ohms is wrong too. How did you calculate these?

Comment: and was my process thought right?

Comment: but from 1/(1/63k + 1/18k) I get 1134k/81k and from that I get 14 not 14k. Unless I'm doing something really wrong ahha

Comment: You might want to double check if you are doing it really wrong.

Comment: oh, i see where the problem is nvm thanks for the input guys

Answer (score 3, accepted):

R4 is 10k not 10 so your initial schematic has an error. Otherwise, your thought process is correct.